# LOCAL SERVER and telnet

Tags: networking, telnet, network-protocols

Finally, after many attempts and days, I managed to connect 2 computers using the telnet client and the telnet server. The reason of so many attempts is because there are no complete guides for these 2 programs, and because I am really noob with this things. My best reference was this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mvzItm0KGXs, but this kind guy doesn't explain completely, and the references from the microsoft website, but they still are not complete.

What I've done:

In the server I:

1. installed the telnet server (tlntsvr.exe)
2. went into "services" and (on the right side) searched for “Telnet”.  Right click on that and chose “Properties”: in “General” changed the “Startup type” from “Automatic” to “Manual” and then clicked “Start” to initialize the telnet server.
3. verified if the telnet server was listening on the port 23 (the port of the telnet): opened the command prompt (CMD) and wrote “netstat –an” (‘a’ is for “all” and ‘n’ for “no names”): telnet was listening on the right port!
4. allowed the client PC to connect to the server: went to “Computer” and right click on the icon and chose “Manage”, chose “Local Users and Groups”, chose “Groups” and clicked on “TelnetClients” group: added a new user to this group: right click on it, chose “Properties” > “Add” > “Advanced” > “Find Now” and searched for a “LOCAL SERVER”, clicked on it and then clicked “Ok”.

In the client I:

1. installed the telnet client (telnet.exe)
2. opened telnet with CMD, wrote "open ". Waited a few seconds. Typed the username and the password of the server account.

What I can't really understand about what I did is the point 4, while I was setting the server: why did it work choosing "LOCAL SERVER" and not, for example, with "network"? I noticed also that if I choose "everyone" (of course) it works as well.

I've heard that telnet is not a good program (or is not good the protocol?), but I didn't understand why. Can you tell me the advantages and disadvantages of this program and of the protocol?

I have little experiences with these kind of programs and in general with protocols and networking. I hope you be patient with me.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you added "LOCAL SERVICE" (not SERVER) to the group properties. What you did in step four is giving the user the right to connect using Telnet. If you have another user which was not added in step four, you shouldn't be able to login with it via Telnet.

And yes **Telnet is completely discouraged** as a protocol because it doesn't provide encryption. You should use **SSH** instead which is more powerful and secure.

Comment: Yes, but if I wanted to connect to a computer outside my network area, should I set it to "everyone" or what?

Comment: I didn't understand what I have to choose for difference situations...what situations? (sorry)

Comment: You are giving permission for local user being used as login credentials to your server. When you add a user to TelnetClients group you allow some to login into your server using that user and password. If you add Everyone you allow any server user (present and future) to connect via telnet.

Comment: Which users can connect to other server, is something configured in other server. Not your server.

Comment: Ok, but if I wanted just to let 1 person to enter in my pc? I didn't really understand how to do it... what is "Enter the objects name to select"? I have to create an object? (sorry)

Comment: For one user only, you have to add just that user to TelnetClients group. Nothing else. I'm not sure why you added "LOCAL SERVICE" too, which looks like an internal group. Can you remove it and check if it works?

Comment: I have to put just the IP address in the section "Enter the objects name to select" ? (sorry, I am really noob to this, unfortunetely, and I am also a bit old and a bit tired: who cares? )

Comment: No. You just have to follow step four until you see TelnetClients group. Then double click on it to see who is inside the group. And then just leave there the users you want to connect via Telnet.

Answer (score 0):

Telnet isn't recommended because it isn't secure ...

If I was to log into a telnet server over the internet, the password (And everything else) would be sent in clear text. So it makes it extremely easy for someone to hack.

SSH is a much better protocol, as it encrypts everything.

Try OpenSSH for your server, and use Putty on your client.

OpenSSH:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/sshwindows/files/OpenSSH%20for%20Windows%20-%20Release/

If you have any questions about setting up OpenSSH, don't hesitate to ask :D

Putty:
http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/x86/putty.exe

Comment: While accurate, this is not an answer to the OPs question.